# Calculation error at runtime in python loan calculator

Tags: python, calculator

I'm trying to build a loan calculator that takes in the amount owed and interest rate per month and the down payment put at the beginning and the monthly installments so it can output how many months do you need to pay off your debt. The program works just fine when I enter an interest_rate below 10% but if I type any number for example 18% it just freezes and gives no output. When I stop running the program it gives me these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Khaled\PycharmProjects\interest_payment\main.py", line 35, in <module>
    months_to_finish = get_months(price)  # this returns the number of months from the counter var
  File "C:\Users\Khaled\PycharmProjects\interest_payment\main.py", line 6, in get_months
    price = price - installments
KeyboardInterrupt
```

This is my code:

```
def get_months(price):
    counter = 0
    price = price - down_payment
    while price > 0:
        price = price + price * interest_rate
        price = price - installments
        counter += 1
    return counter


if __name__ == '__main__':
    price = float(input("Enter price here: "))
    interest_rate = float(input("Enter interest rate here: %")) / 100
    while interest_rate < 0:
        interest_rate = float(input('Invalid interest rate please try again: %')) / 100
    down_payment = int(input("Enter your down payment here: $"))
    while down_payment > price or down_payment < 0:
        down_payment = int(input('Invalid down payment please try again: $'))

    choice = input("Decision based on Installments (i) or Months to finish (m), please write i or m: ").lower()
    if choice == 'm':
        print('m')


    elif choice == 'i':
        installments = int(input("What's your monthly installment budget: "))  # get the installments
        months_to_finish = get_months(price)  # this returns the number of months from the counter var
        print(f"It will take {months_to_finish} months to finish your purchase.")
    else:
        print('Invalid choice program ended')
```

These are the test values:
Enter price here: 22500
Enter interest rate here: %18
Enter your down payment here: $0
Decision based on Installments (i) or Months to finish (m), please write i or m: i
What's your monthly installment budget: 3000

Comment: What debugging have you done? Set breakpoints in your while loops and after your inputs to see where the code is "stuck"

Comment: Price gets to infinity when interest rate is above 13.

Comment: Your parameters are loan-shark parameters. You will never pay it off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With an initial principal of $22,500, an interest rate of 18%, a down payment of $0, and a monthly payment of $3,000, it will take an infinite number of months to pay off the loan. After one period at 18% interest, you have accrued $4,050 of interest. Since you're only paying $3,000 per period, you're not even covering the amount of new interest, and the total amount you owe will grow forever. You probably want to check somewhere that the monthly payment is greater than the first month's interest. You could modify your code like this:

```
if installments < (price - down_payment) * interest_rate:
    print("The purchase cannot be made with these amounts.")
else:
    months_to_finish = get_months(price)
    print(f"It will take {months_to_finish} months to finish your purchase.")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l=[]
n=int(input())
i=0
for i in range(n):
    l.append(str(input()))
def long(x):
    if x>10:
        return print(l[i][0]+str(len(l[i])-2)+l[i][-1])
def short(x):
    if x<=10:
        return print(l[i])
i=0
for i in range(len(l[i])):
    long(len(l[i]))
    short(len(l[i]))
    continue
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).